# How to randomly set text to four buttons from SQLite db?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a SQLite table imported in assets, trial one with 10 rows and 6 columns (_ID, QUESTION, ANSWER, OPTION1, OPTION2 AND OPTION3). I managed to read random row from database and assign that data, one question to a textview, and four possible answers to my buttons  with this code:

```
TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();

        mDbHelper.open();

        final Cursor c = mDbHelper.getTestData();

        question.setText(c.getString(1));
        bOdgovor1.setText(c.getString(2));
        bOdgovor2.setText(c.getString(3));
        bOdgovor3.setText(c.getString(4));
        bOdgovor4.setText(c.getString(5));
```

I also have this line in my TestAdapter class:

```
String sql ="SELECT * FROM tblPitanja ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
```

This is all good, but I wont randomly to assign questions to buttons, cause this way every time the answer is at button 1. How to  mix questions between  my buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your strings into a list and use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%3C?%3E%29) to shuffle them around.

Here's an example:

```
List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

labels.add(c.getString(2));
labels.add(c.getString(3));
labels.add(c.getString(4));
labels.add(c.getString(5));

Collections.shuffle(labels);

bOdgovor1.setText(labels.get(0));
bOdgovor2.setText(labels.get(1));
bOdgovor3.setText(labels.get(2));
bOdgovor4.setText(labels.get(3));
```

Comment: Is there a way just to upgrade this code to eliminate repeating? I don't want questions to repeat in one session. Other than that it works fine.

Comment: Repetition should be handled in your SQL statement. Just keep the id of the questions you've asked before filter new questions by their id with `WHERE` statement.

Comment: I didn't quite catch what you said. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Just change your sql statement to `String sql ="SELECT * FROM tblPitanja WHERE _id NOT IN (...) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";` where `...` is a comma separated list of the ids you've already used. Keep in mind that you won't need to use this type of query the first time around as there is no previous question.

Comment: Yes, but questions are drawn randomly, how can I know what ids to put there if I don't know what questions will be drawn?

Comment: You have to use the ids of the questions you've already used, which is straightforward since you just keep on adding the ids to a list for every new question. If you look closely, the SQL statement says `WHERE _id NOT IN (...)`, as in, any question as long as the id of the question is not part of this list. You should read up about how SQLite handles SQL statements through this link: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

Comment: I know what NOT IN does but I don't know how to use that in my situation. Can you give an example using my code, so I can move on from there?

Comment: Perhaps you should create a new question with this topic, since this is a different thing altogether from the question you have posted here.

Comment: OK, I did it. Here's the link, check it out. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185495/how-to-randomly-set-text-to-buttons-from-sqlite-without-repetition)